# T-SQL equivalent of C++ #define

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL-Script for changing the source tables of multiple views at once. To do so I would like to have something like

```
#define source theSourceTable
```

instead of finding and replacing the parts I need. My understanding is that this isn't possible with local variables but is there another way?

Comment: That sounds tricky. I guess you would have to store the `alter view..` code in a variable, replace the old table name with the new one, and dynamic-sql-execute the new var value.

Comment: Is this something you have to do frequently? If so, this sounds like a design flaw; bur if so have you considered using a `SYNONYM`? If it's a one off then it would seem easier to just change the relevant DDL.

Comment: @Larnu, for now, I actually do need this every few months because I'm working on a test system in which the table names change fairly regularly. I just read up on `SYNONYM` and I'm afraid it's not really applicable for me. The concrete application is that tables are named `partThatChanges$partThatDoesNotChange`. Therefore I'm looking for a way to change the bit before the $ for all views at once without changing the bit after the $ since that is individual for each view.

Comment: Why would a synonym not work for that..?

Comment: Yeah sounds to me like a synonym is a great solution. Once you change the table name you simply change the synonym and your queries just work.

Comment: My answer below is a literal response to an equivalent to #define, but thinking about it the synonym idea might be best for your situation

Comment: I suppose you guys are right. I might have misread something on synonyms. Cheers for helping me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, a `SYNONYM`, seems to the right idea here. As we have very little to work with, here is an overly simplified example:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO
--Create some sample tables
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable1 (MyColumn int);
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable1 (MyColumn)
VALUES (1),(2);

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable2 (MyColumn int);
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable2 (MyColumn)
VALUES (3),(4);
GO
--Create synonyms
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.MyTableA FOR dbo.MyTable1;
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.MyTableB FOR dbo.MyTable1;
GO
--Create views
CREATE VIEW MyView1 AS
    SELECT MyColumn, 'View1' AS ObjectName
    FROM dbo.MyTableA;
GO

CREATE VIEW MyView2 AS
    SELECT MyColumn, 'View2' AS ObjectName
    FROM dbo.MyTableB;
GO

CREATE VIEW MyView3 AS
    SELECT A.MyColumn AS AColumn,
          B.MyColumn AS BColumn,
          'View3' AS ObjectName
    FROM dbo.MyTableA A
         CROSS JOIN dbo.MyTableB B;
GO
--Check data
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyView1;
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyView2;
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyView3;
GO
--Create a new table
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable3 (MyColumn int);
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable3 (MyColumn)
VALUES (5),(6);
GO
--Alter the synonyms
DROP SYNONYM dbo.MyTableA;
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.MyTableA FOR dbo.MyTable2;
DROP SYNONYM dbo.MyTableB;
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.MyTableB FOR dbo.MyTable3;
GO
--Check views again:
--Check data
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyView1;
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyView2;
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyView3;
GO
--Clean up
DROP VIEW dbo.MyView1;
DROP VIEW dbo.MyView2;
DROP VIEW dbo.MyView3;
DROP SYNONYM dbo.MyTableA;
DROP SYNONYM dbo.MyTableB;
DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable1;
DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable2;
DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable3;
```

You will need to edit the existing DDL of all your views once, to use the new synonym's name instead, but after that you can simply recreate the synonyms and they will all be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use SQLCMD mode (activate with ALT-Q-M or toggle it in the Query menu in SSMS).

```
:SETVAR MyTable SomeTableName

CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.myView
AS

SELECT * FROM dbo.$(MyTable)
GO
```

This will end up with a view that selects * from SomeTableName

Alternatively you can possibly use dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @myTable VARCHAR(100) = 'SomeTableName'

SET @sql = 'CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.myView
AS

SELECT * FROM dbo.' + @myTable

EXEC(@sql)
```

which has the same end result.

(CREATE OR ALTER is SQL2016 syntactic sugar, if you are on an older version adjust accordingly)

Comment: Synonym idea is probably better, but I'll leave this as it might be interesting for other visitors with different needs